# JS-Hint not giving warnings errors in webpack

Tags: webpack, jshint

I have installed dependency for all that I know ( the folders are in my build ) by typing 
`npm install jshint jshint-loader --save-dev`. Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
`module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders : [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'jshint-loader' 
        }
    ]
  }
}`
```

I have webpack in the dev environment with watch working. But say I write `consol.logg('wut')` and save in my app.js...there are no warnings or errors and webpack says my bundle is VALID.

Answer (score 0):

`jshint` processes the output "path" which is not configured.
So you just need to adjust the project structure slightly to output into a sub "path" location.

Remember to adjust the link to `bundle.js` in your HTML.